# How to change the ATL control default width and height?

Tags: c, winapi, atl

I am using `ATL control` to make my `ActiveX`, but the problem is when I start the app. The width and height always are fixed and small.

[image]

But I want to change the width. I changed the code below, but it did not work. So how to solve this problem?

```
HRESULT OnDraw(ATL_DRAWINFO& di)
{
    RECT& rc = *(RECT*)di.prcBounds;
    rc.left = 0;
    rc.top = 0;
    rc.right = 700;
    rc.bottom = 500;

    HDC hdc = di.hdcDraw;
    TCHAR wcScore[20];
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    initialize(hdc,rc);
    paint(hdc,rc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally,I solved my problem by myself.code blew.

```
<OBJECT ID="PolyCtrl"  width="700" height="500" CLASSID="CLSID:F05493DC-007F-4C6A-A2F9-824B2BEA5BAB"></OBJECT>
```